# django-dynamic-formset add another / delete buttons failing

Tags: javascript, django, inline-formset, dynamicform

[Screenshot of the error]

You can find the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D4l2.png

Hi,
I'm a beginner Django developer writing my first question in stackoverflow.  I'm trying to use the django-dynamic-formset plugin to enable the user of my web application to add or delete forms dynamically, by clicking a button, however, instead of getting a "remove" button for every row, I'm getting one for every field in my form as you can see in the picture.  Also, when I'm trying to customize the text in the "add another" or "delete" button, this is not working (you can see the script at the end of my html template).  I would appreciate if you can tell me what I might be doing wrong.  I'm attaching the code of my html template as well.

```
`{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<table class="formset-test">
  {{formset.management_form|crispy}}
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row-{{formset.prefix}}">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <td>
          {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
              {{hidden}}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
          {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<!-- <p class='btn btn-warning' id='agregar'>Agregar Posición</p> -->
<br>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dynamic_formsets/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#agregar').on('click',function(){
    $('.formset-test').append()
  });
</script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar posición',
        deleteText: 'Borrar posición',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
</script>
`
```

Comment: Update: It worked when I replaced the plugin with the version 1.3 available here: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js

Comment: Nevertheless it would be great if anyone could tell me what was wrong, I'm still confused

Comment: After weeks in despair I have come across this answer and I finally arrived to the solution. What did it was this: prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}', i had been instructed erroneously by another guide to put the name of the database relation instead.